# Changing views by swiping

Tags: ios, view, slide

i am a newbie in Cocoa/Objective-C so I hope you can help me with this question:

I have two View Controllers in two different xib's and i want to switch between these with a swipe of a finger on the screen.

Can anyone give me an advise please:)

Comment: You are talking about iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you to achieve with switching between the views with a swipe, there are a few ways to do it.

Here are a few that come to mind:

- UIScrollView with those views as subviews. You can set the Scroll View to paging mode and it handles all swiping for you.
- Using `UIGestureRecognizer`s, particularly the UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Add it to both views and create a "master" class that decides what happens when such gesture is performed by the user.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I will try UIGestureRecognizer.. But first I have to learn something about this and read some informations. I have further questions accuring i will post it :)